# Black soot on the exhaust pipe of subaru forester sg5 turbo

Tags: engine

I am experiensing some black soot from the exhaust pipe of my forester sg5 turbo. This started after changing to a bigger turbo(td04hl). What could this mean and the advisable repair? Kindly

Comment: That you have not checked the relevant settings to match the different turbo. Why did you fit a larger, possibly incorrect, turbo?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

There's three things I can think of:

1. Bad tune
2. A stuck injector, or
3. You've got a leak in your charge pipe.

Soot indicates too much fuel (or conversely not enough air). If you don't find any leaks on the charge side, the mapping in your tune is dumping too much fuel, or you might have a stuck injector, also dumping too much fuel.